# Having trouble to loop through a file containing XPaths

Tags: loops, selenium, xpath, python-3.5

I am having trouble to loop through a file `day.txt` containing XPaths.
For example: I already tried to triple quote in the file like this:

```
"""//[@id="frm"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]"""
```

but it's not working.

The error is

> SyntaxError:
>     Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':
>     The string '"""//*[@id="frm"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/span"""
>   '
>   is not a valid XPath expression.

Any help is welcome!

```
dates = open("days.txt")
for date in dates:
 date.strip()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(date).click()
```

Comment: I believe it should be `[@id='frm']` with single quote around `frm`.

Comment: @Guy, This is not the reason: in `Python` string like `"""text"with"double-quotes"""` is valid. The problem is that values from `days.txt` are already of type `string` and OP shouldn't add `"""`

Comment: @Guy, just found the solution for the loop with xpath. '("""{}""".format(date)).click()' works fine for my purpose. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any quotes around the lines in the txt file. If your XPath locators contain double quotes ("), you will need to replace them all with single quotes (') before using them. If you google replacing characters in a string in python, you'll find some example code.

NOTE: Locators that contain that many levels are very brittle. You really need to handcraft those locators to make them much shorter.

Comment: Can you clarify why OP might need to replace double quotes with single quotes in `XPath`?

Comment: Just found the solution for the loop with xpath. ("""{}""".format(date)).click() works fine for my purpose. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!